# how to stop PHP to catch errors in an array loop?

Tags: php

I am trying to loop through an array of four servers. I am trying to find a user on those servers. I am able to see the program works but PHP throws errors from the servers it cannot find from the array. Could someone help how to avoid those errors?

```
 $ID = '1234';
    
 $server_list = array("example1.com", "example2.com", "example3.com");
    
 function serverQuery($server_array, $ID){
    foreach ($server_array as $value) {
        $host = $value;
        try{
            include('info.php');
            $response = $client->getUser(array("name" => ID))->return;
            //print_r($response);
        }catch (Exception $e){
            echo "Print the error";
        }
    }
    }
```

Every time I search the user, it did fine in one of the servers but "Print the Error" is also printed along with it. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: You should take a look at [PSR-1 2.3](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#23-side-effects) before continuing IMHO. Does it throw an Exception? Does it print? Where does it do this? What is `$client`?

Comment: Why don't you echo `$e->getMessage()` to see what is wrong? Also it should be clear, that you pass an constant, but mean the `$ID` variable (missing dollar sign).

Comment: I'm curious why you are including a file on every loop.

Comment: Item not valid: The specified User was not found
The above is the error when i used $e->getMessage()